# A shorter language detection

Tags: php, url

I need a way to include a php file based on the language in the URL. Right now this script is working, but when I have 10 or 20 languages I would like some sort of shorter script, that still contains the same information. The thing is, if the 'lg' in the URL is changed to a language that doesn't exist, I would like to use the english language.

```
$langue=$_GET['lg'];
if ($langue == "da")
{ include"da.php";}
elseif ($langue == "de")
{ include"de.php";}
elseif ($langue == "en")
{ include"en.php";}
elseif ($langue == "es")
{ include"es.php";}
else { include"en.php";}
```

Anybody who can shorten this one?

Comment: you have just accepted the code that will make your site easily hacked/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (empty($_GET['lg'])) {
  $lang = "en";
} else {
  $lang = $_GET['lg'];
}
if ( !preg_match('~^[a-z]{2}$~',$lang) ) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'); 
  exit;
}
$langfile = "$lang.php";
if (!is_readable($langfile)) {
  $lang     = "en";
  $langfile = 'en.php';
}
include $langfile;
```

Comment: This works, but it does a stat to check if the file exists on the disk everything, which is an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: when it will be the only stat issued by my application per request, not one of hundreds as it is at the moment - I'd start thinking of optimizing it

Comment: Okay.. it seems to that this is actually the best script... But my question is, since there has been a lot about security.: Do I have to combine this script by using an "allowed" array? and could you tell me what the "preg_match" is for?

Comment: @Philip Right for the security it is. it checks if $lang consists only of 2 lowercase latin letters and send "access forbidden" response otherwise. So, there cannot be anything harmful anymore. So, it does some sort of automation - you don't need to update an array with another language added. it's also does variaous error checking and allows graceful fallback - your site will be up as long as it has at least en language file

Comment: @Philip there was an error in both regexp and syntax. corrected it now

Comment: The thing is that I start with a javascript that finds the browser language - but sometimes the language can be like en-gb, and if that happens I would need a language file named en-gb.php which cannot be accepted since the script only allows 2 letter files. Is that correct?

Comment: @Philip do you have `en-gb.php` file? if so - is there a difference from `en.php`?

Comment: I see your point... This is a site for europe and I would like to create as many languages as dialects... And also.. if the browser language is es-pa then the site will automatically use en.php, but it would be more obvious to use the es.php since it is a spanish language..

Comment: I will.. This is definitely the best script for my use for now... :) I will maybe develop a little on it, when I have some more languages to it with.. Thank you very much for your time and help..

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$lang = (file_exists($_GET['lg'] . '.php')) ? $_GET['lg'] . '.php' : 'en.php';
include($lang);
```

**Edit**: As per the comments I should point out that this code, although functional and concise, is indeed highly vulnerable to malicious attacks, essentially anyone could set the URL variable to a configuration or other sensitive file, and then launch an attack on your site, or steal your data. So make sure you validate the `$lang` variable before calling include - maybe with a simple:

```
$allowed = array('en.php', 'fr.php');
if(in_array($lang, $allowed)){
    include($lang);
}
```

Comment: I don't know.. I haven't done anything but mark it as correct.. :/

Comment: It's ok, evidentially some people just can't stand concise code!

Comment: for the obvious vulnerability

Comment: Well yes the code is vulnerable, and when deployed it would be best to actually validate the variable, but as a start point it works.

Comment: Go tell it to the OP, not me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $languages = array('da', 'de', 'en', 'es');

    $lang = 'en';
    if(!empty($_GET['lg']) && array_search($_GET['lg'], $languages) !== false) {
        $lang = $_GET['lg'];
    }
    include $lang.'.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['lg']) && $_REQUEST['lg'] != '') $lg = $_REQUEST['lg'];

if(strstr($lg, '.')) die('Don\'t allow any . in the languages');

if(file_exists('path_to_language_files/'.$lg.'.php') {
    include('path_to_language_files/'.$lg.'.php');
} else {
    include('path_to_language_files/en.php');
}
```

Comment: When I used the script there were a few mistakes due to missing ')' and the "Don't allow any..." command was destroyed because of the single quotes.. But when I am reading the script it seems fine, I just have a question about this one..

    if (isset($_REQUEST['lg'] && $_REQUEST['lg'] != ''))

How do I change this to be right? It keeps telling there is a mistake...

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, I have updated the code now, so now it should be ok, but you have probably fixed it already :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a page which uses only two languages but i needed it to be open for adding more and so, i solved the same problem like this:

```
$allowed=array("da","de","en","es");
$default="de.php";
include(array_search($_GET["lg"],$allowed) === false ? $default : $allowed[array_search($_GET["lg"] , $allowed)].".php");
```

It should work similarly, except you can specify which files are allowed, and their names are taken from the array, so it should be safe from fake requests.

Comment: You're a bit late with this answer

Comment: Tried to avoid your insecure code, anyway you upgraded it so its ok.